# How about some automatic syntax-highlighting on meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, syntax-highlighting

AFAICS, there's just one tag on meta which has a high incidence of code in a predictable language:
[data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)

How about we add a highlighting-hint for that?

Comment: I'm for this, good suggestion.